# Can "Run" but can't "Debug" Cordova in PhpStorm 8

Tags: cordova, phpstorm

I've set up my PhpStorm to [use the PhoneGap/Cordova plugin](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/using-phonegap-cordova.html#d286535e300) and it works insofar as I can go to [Run > Run](http://puu.sh/i10h3/ccff6cb69c.png) to run `cordova emulate ios` with [this Run configuration](http://puu.sh/i10jD/209f4a7468.png).

However, for some reason it won't let me Debug (so I can't use breakpoints or inspect variable values) and I can't get any `console.log` output either.

I'm not entirely sure why I can Run but not Debug - any ideas?

Comment: Simple: there is not debug support yet -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14781

Comment: @LazyOne if you want to post that as an answer with the source, I'll tick it for you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware debugging Cordova/PhoneGap/Ionic applications is not yet implemented.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14781 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.

---

Based on [ToDo List](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-plugins/tree/master/phoneGap#todo-list) of that plugin it does not look like debugging support is in their nearest plans (plus, aforementioned ticket has only 4 or so votes so far -- way too little).

Comment: Cheers. The best workaround I've found is to use [Safari's dev tools](http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/debugging-ios-phonegap-apps-with-safaris-web-inspector.html) to inspect the DOM and access the console (ignore the iPhone settings changes in the linked article)